# React.js .map is not a function, mapping Firebase result

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to react and Firebase and I really struggle with arrays and objects I'm guessing that you can't use `.map` with the way my data is formatted (or type). I've looked through stack but nothing has helped (at least in my poor efforts to implement fixes).

I am trying to use `.map` to map through a result from firebase but I get the error **TypeError:** `this.state.firebasedata.map` **is not a function**.

getting the data:

```
componentWillMount(){
this.getVideosFromFirebase()

}

getVideosFromFirebase(){
  var youtubeVideos = firebase.database().ref('videos/');
  youtubeVideos.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    const firebasedata = snapshot.val();
    this.setState({firebasedata});
  });
}
```

[image]

relevant states:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    firebasedata: []
  }
  };
```

.map in render:

```
render(){
  return(
    <div>
         {this.state.firebasedata.map((item) =>
            <div key="{item}">
            <p>{item.video.name}</p>
            </div>
         )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you do a `console.log(this.state.firebasedata)` in your render function ? My guess is you need to do `this.state.firebasedata.videos.map`

Comment: This is because the response is most probably not an array.. seems it is an object. can you `console.log(firebasedata)` before `setState`?

Comment: Make sure `firebasedata` state is an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `firebase` does not store data as arrays, but instead as objects. So the response you're getting is an object.

> Firebase has no native support for arrays. If you store an array, it really gets stored as an "object" with integers as the key names.

Read [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) for more on why firebase stores data as objects.

To map over objects you can do something like

```
Object.keys(myObject).map(function(key, index) {
   console.log(myObject[key])
});
```

Comment: Thanks this helped completely fixing my issue, you're a legend! Cheers! I really do appreciate it so much!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here now, you can simply type `snapshot.docs` to get an array of all the documents in the relevant collection.

As an example, if you want to get all user objects from the collection `users` you can do the following:

```js
const getAllUsers = async () => {
    const usersSnapshot = await db.collection('users').get()
    const allUsers = usersSnapshot.docs.map(userDoc => userDoc.data())
    return allUsers
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted above Firebase snap.val() - is an object.

When you have to go through object you can also simply use for each:

```
for(var key in this.state.firebasedata){
   <div key="{key}">
   <p>{this.state.firebasedata[key].video.name}</p>
   </div>
}
```

I also recommend creating a separate method for it, and call it in render.
Hope this helps